# I have no idea what could possibly be bugged

Tags: c, undefined, keccak

So I'm trying to write my own "keccaksum" program, except running

```
for i in {1..50}; do ./keccaksum 256 test.o; done
```

outputs

```
4d4cc035e544cd4837b45550094dd3c419e380af3b0c74109c00053c7ed82040  test.o
```

most of the time and

```
b19d21947b7228da366b4d26f232b87e21999ff1a220c37c9bed6553260068c0  test.o
```

some of the time.

The relevant function(s) here is

```
void printsum(const char *_fname, FILE *_f, size_t size){   
    uint64_t state[25];
    uint8_t *hash = malloc(size * sizeof(uint8_t));
    uint8_t buf[25];
    uint8_t tmp[144];
    register int i, rsize, rsizew;
    register size_t j;

    rsize = 200 - 2 * size;
    rsizew = rsize / 8;

    //Clear the state
    memset(state, 0, sizeof(state));

    while(1) {
        //read up to rsize bytes, then do work
        j = fread(buf, 1, rsize, _f);

        //check some stuff
        if(feof(_f)){
            break;
        } else if(ferror(_f)){
            fprintf(stderr, "Error when reading %s.\n", _fname);
            goto fin;
        } else {
            //First few blocks (i.e. not last block)
            for(i = 0; i < rsizew; i++)
                state[i] ^= ((uint64_t *)buf)[i];
            keccakf(state, KECCAK_ROUNDS);
        }
    }

    //Last block + padding
    memcpy(tmp, buf, j);
    tmp[j++] = 1;
    memset(tmp + j, 0, rsize - j);
    tmp[rsize - 1] |= 0x80;

    for(i = 0; i < rsizew; i++)
        state[i] ^= ((uint64_t *)tmp)[i];
    keccakf(state, KECCAK_ROUNDS);

    //copy hash
    memcpy(hash, state, size);

    //print
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) printf("%02x", hash[i]);
    printf("  %s\n", _fname);

fin:    
    if(_f != stdin) fclose(_f);
    free(hash);
}
```

This leads me to believe that some part of this code is undefined and I have no idea what could possibly be undefined.

Comment: are you sure that `rsize <= 25`?

Comment: `(200 - 2 * size) / 8 <= 25`...

Comment: note that you are doing `rsizew = rsize / 8` and using `rsize` to read into the buffer.

Comment: `rsize = 200 - 2 * size` so that should be true

Comment: just check it and make sure it is true. And use valgrind if possible.

Comment: added a sanity check and it is true even with the derp output

Comment: just realized that buf was too small (for the memcpy) which caused some derps. increased its size to 200 and everything works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

First of all replace this:

```
if(feof(_f)){
        break;
    } else if(ferror(_f)){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error when reading %s.\n", _fname);
        goto fin;
    } else {
        for(i = 0; .....
```

with this:

```
if ( j < rsize )
    break;

for (i = 0; .......
```

If you care about which error message to show, you can check `ferror` after the loop.

Next, this may cause undefined behaviour depending on your system's alignment requirements:

```
state[i] ^= ((uint64_t *)buf)[i];
```

To be safe you could replace this with:

```
{
    uint64_t temp;
    memcpy(&temp, buf + i * sizeof temp, sizeof temp);
    state[i] ^= temp;
}
```

However it's not clear to me whether this is the correct behaviour for the keccak algorithm if your system is little-endian; nor if this is correct in the case that `size` is not an exact multiple of `8`.

There are various other errors which may occur for certain values of `size`. You made it difficult by not specifying which values of `size` are causing the problem. It would be very helpful if you update your post to show a full program. (i.e. something that someone else can compile unchanged to reproduce the problem). In the meantime:

If `size > 100` then this will go haywire.

For small values of `size` this is a buffer overflow:

```
uint8_t tmp[144];
memcpy(tmp, buf, j);
tmp[j++] = 1;
memset(tmp + j, 0, rsize - j);
tmp[rsize - 1] |= 0x80;
```

because `rsize` could be up to `200` and this will overflow `tmp`. Also, think about whether you want to execute this block in the case `j == 0`.

In this line `memcpy(hash, state, size);` it's weird that the number of bytes you operate on is `rsizew * 8`, but the number of bytes you copy is `size`, these will not be the same in general.

I'll update my post after you post the full program, to take into account the actual values of `size` in use.

NB. Is this supposed to be SHA-3?